# Why Is This Script Not Working? - Aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have been trying to figure out how two scripts that I've used in my prior aframe project are not working in this new aframe project I am working on now. I used the exact same code and altered a few things but nothing that should render the scripts useless. The problem with the recent project is the cubes should highlight when the mouse/cursor rolls over them, and when clicked it should send the user to a new URL. Take a look at the examples below. Thank you in advance!

Here is the prior project: http://www.nightmaresinparis.com

And here is the recent project: http://www.fakereal.co

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Script For Highlighting -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Script For Web Travel -->
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('navigate-on-click', {
      schema: {
        url: {
          default: ''
        }
      },

      init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;

        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
          window.location.href = data.url;
        });
      }
    });
  </script>


  <title> YC EXPERIENCE </title>



</head>


<body>
  <a-scene>


    <a-assets>
      <img id="sky" src="http://fakereal.co/cyberspace.jpg">
      <img id="buzzingtracks" src="http://www.fakereal.co/buzzingtracksmarch.png">
      <img id="animesunday" src="http://www.fakereal.co/animesundaygraphic.png">
      <img id="ycoriginals" src="http://www.fakereal.co/ycoriginalsgraphic.png">
      <img id="wallpapers" src="http://www.fakereal.co/wallpapersgraphic.png">
    </a-assets>

    <!-- Sky -->
    <a-sky src="#sky" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>

    <!-- Buzzing Tracks -->
    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="-1399.286 -66.072 5.656" rotation="0 -316.189 0" src="#buzzingtracks" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #FFFF00"
      event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #FFFFFF">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>
    <!-- Anime Sunday -->

    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="-835.773 -100.22 -1217.11" rotation="0 -320.0374406229489 0" src="#animesunday" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]"
      event-set__leave="[object Object]">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- YC Originals -->
    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="264.552 -105.496 -1242.917" rotation="0 -320.0354311738257 0" src="#ycoriginals" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]" event-set__leave="[object Object]"
      material="">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- Wallpapers -->

    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="1392.653 -115.664 -278.839" rotation="0 -323.90948623644624 0" src="#wallpapers" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]"
      event-set__leave="[object Object]">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- Camera -->

    <a-camera position="-5.516 -7.6 11.396" rotation="2.8647889756541165 4.182591904455009 0" camera="active:true" look-controls="" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" fuse="true" wasd-controls="" raycaster="" data-aframe-inspector-original-camera="">

      <a-entity fuse="true" fusetimeout="50000" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive:ring;radiusInner:0.02;radiusOuter:0.03" material="shader:flat;color:cyan" raycaster="">
      </a-entity>

    </a-camera>

  </a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just links to your projects, since you'll update the code in your projects when you get the answer.

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212), then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I apologize @Barmar I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many minor issues with your code, I change some bits around `<!-- Camera -->` - but it started working after setting `raycaster="far: 5000"` - boxes were too far for raycaster to check for intersections as the default is `1000`. **Make sure to uncomment:** `//window.location.href = data.url;`
Official docs are wrong on this one, it says that default value for raycaster's `far` attribute is `Infinity`, but looking into source code it is in fact `1000`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Script For Highlighting -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Script For Web Travel -->
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('navigate-on-click', {
      schema: {
        url: {
          default: ''
        }
      },

      init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;
        console.log(el);
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
          //window.location.href = data.url;
          console.log("works");
        });
      }
    });
  </script>


  <title> YC EXPERIENCE </title>



</head>


<body>
  <a-scene>


    <a-assets>
      <img id="sky" src="http://fakereal.co/cyberspace.jpg">
      <img id="buzzingtracks" src="http://www.fakereal.co/buzzingtracksmarch.png">
      <img id="animesunday" src="http://www.fakereal.co/animesundaygraphic.png">
      <img id="ycoriginals" src="http://www.fakereal.co/ycoriginalsgraphic.png">
      <img id="wallpapers" src="http://www.fakereal.co/wallpapersgraphic.png">
    </a-assets>

    <!-- Sky -->
    <a-sky src="#sky" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>

    <!-- Buzzing Tracks -->
    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="-1399.286 -66.072 5.656" rotation="0 -316.189 0" src="#buzzingtracks" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #FFFF00"
      event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #FFFFFF">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>
    <!-- Anime Sunday -->

    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="-835.773 -100.22 -1217.11" rotation="0 -320.0374406229489 0" src="#animesunday" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]"
      event-set__leave="[object Object]">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- YC Originals -->
    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="264.552 -105.496 -1242.917" rotation="0 -320.0354311738257 0" src="#ycoriginals" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]" event-set__leave="[object Object]"
      material="">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- Wallpapers -->

    <a-box width="500" height="500" depth="500" position="1392.653 -115.664 -278.839" rotation="0 -323.90948623644624 0" src="#wallpapers" navigate-on-click="url: yugencreations://#!section=16787412" color="#FFFFFF" shadow="" event-set__enter="[object Object]"
      event-set__leave="[object Object]">

      <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="0 -500 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

    </a-box>


    <!-- Camera -->

    <a-entity camera rotation="2.8647889756541165 4.182591904455009 0" look-controls wasd-controls data-aframe-inspector-original-camera>
    <a-entity position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive:ring;radiusInner:0.01;radiusOuter:0.02" material="shader:flat;color:cyan" raycaster="far: 5000" cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1500">
      </a-entity>
      

    </a-entity>

  </a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomaszBubala that got the boxes highlighting properly, any ideas what could be going on with the URLs? I have it working with regular links but using deeplinks seems to be a problem. Do you have an idea for this also ?